# Using Navigation's actions instead of direct fragment id crashes app

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-safe-args

I'm having an issue with a very simple task with Navigation component.
I have just 2 screens: MainFragment and SearchFragment.

When I try to go from MainFragment to SearchFragment by navigation with an action it works perfectly. Then I press the back button and naturally it goes back to the MainFragment.

The issue is, when I click the same button the second time to go again to the SearchFragment, I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination action_mainFragment_to_searchFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(searchFragment)
```

I'm navigating from the MainFragment to Search like this:

```
findNavController().navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToSearchFragment())
```

I tried redoing the nav_graph.xml but without success.

If I just navigate with the id directly, it works fine and I go back and forth as many times as I want

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.searchFragment)
```

Any ideas how to fix the issue with the safe args?

Edit:

This is my nav_graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="news.presentation.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_searchFragment"
            app:destination="@id/searchFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:name="news.presentation.search.SearchFragment"
        android:label="fragment_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />
</navigation>
```

This is the activity (it's basically just a container for the fragments):

This is the `activity_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/homeFragContainer"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_main"
    tools:context=".presentation.HomeActivity" />
```

And this is the `HomeActivity.kt`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_home)
```

This is the HomeFragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    private val binding by viewBinding(FragmentMainBinding::bind)
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

    private val articlesAdapter = ArticlesAdapter(::onSubscriptionClicked)
    private lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, bundle: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, bundle)
        setupViews()
        setupViewModel()
        setupRecyclerView()
    }

    private fun setupViews() {
        binding.toolbar.title = getString(R.string.app_name)
        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.intent.offer(MainViewModel.Intent.SearchClicked)
        }
    }

    private fun setupViewModel() {
        viewModel.state
            .onEach(::handleState)
            .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
        viewModel.feedFlow
            .onEach(articlesAdapter::submitList)
            .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        binding.recycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
        binding.recycler.adapter = articlesAdapter
        binding.recycler.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                val canScroll = recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)
                binding.toolbar.isLifted = canScroll
            }
        })
    }

    private fun onSubscriptionClicked(article: Article) {
        viewModel.intent.offer(MainViewModel.Intent.ItemClicked(article))
    }

    private fun handleState(state: MainViewModel.State) = when (state) {
        NavigateToSearch -> findNavController().navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToSearchFragment())
        is FeedReady -> binding.progress.isVisible = false
        Loading -> binding.progress.isVisible = true
        is NavigateToArticle -> {
            // works
            // findNavController().navigate(
            //     R.id.articleFragment,
            //     bundleOf("articleLink" to state.link)
            // )
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the XML for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".presentation.main.MainFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_article_big" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard"
        android:text="Add Feed"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

    <tgo1014.news.presentation.customview.LiftableToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: show the navGraph and how you are navigating from SearchFragment to MainFragment

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem I edited my question and added the nav_graph

Comment: everything looks right. try this `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_searchFragment)`

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this one crashes as well with the same error. I've no idea why the first time it works and then after pressing back and trying again it fails.

Comment: at least now we know that the error is not related with the safeArgs plugin. Show me your activity

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem just added to my question. It's basically just a container for the fragments.

Comment: ok. So the error is in the MainFragment. Show it

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem just added it. I would like to thank you for your time :)

Comment: call this `Log.d("test", findNavController().currentDestination?.label.toString())` before call `navigate` and check if it is esqual to "fragment_main"

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Looks like this is a good step to the right direction. It's returning this: ```D/test: fragment_main
D/test: fragment_main
D/test: fragment_search``` for some reason the second time the method is being called two times. I'm trying to figure out how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error is due to the lifecycle.
Replace this:

```
viewModel.state
    .onEach(::handleState)
    .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

by

```
viewModel.state
    .onEach(::handleState)
    .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I guess the issue is how I'm declaring the state. RIght now it's `val state = MutableSharedFlow<State>()` but I think it's not doing what I want

Comment: now you should remove the activity and navGraph from your question

Comment: I think I found the issue but I'm not really sure how to fix it. Looks like when I'm in the `SearchFragment` and press back, the `MainFragment` is recreated, calling the `setupViewModel()` inside the `onViewCreated()` one more time, where it subscribes again to the ` viewModel.state` flow. Somehow then the fragment collects the same emission two times, causing the issue I described in my question.

Comment: Looks like changing the scope to `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` fixes the issue! If you can edit your question with it I can set it as correct :) Thank you so much for your help and time!

Comment: thanks but you fixed the issue yourself. Write your own answer